# Find Missing Values Between 3 Tables

Tags: t-sql

I have 3 tables: Permissions, Roles, and RolePermissions.  I would like to have a way to select Roles that are missing new rows in the Permissions table based on the RolePermissions table relationship to insert those values once new permissions are added.

I have had no luck finding how this can be done so that is why I'm asking here.

Table structure

```
Permissions | Roles | RolePermissions
------------------------------------------
Id          | Id    | Id
Name        | Name  | RoleId
            |       | PermissionId
```

Idea of sql but I know it's not correct:

```
-- Looking to be able to do something like
INSERT INTO RolePermissions (RoleId, PermissionId)
SELECT missingpermissions.PermissionId, missingpermissions.RoleId
FROM Permissions as p
INNER JOIN(
Select r.Id as RoleId,  p.Id as PermissionId
    FROM Role as r
    LEFT JOIN RolePermissions as rp
        ON r.Id = rp.RoleId
    WHERE rp.PermissionId = p.Id
) as missingpermissions 
ON p.id = missingpermissions.permissionid
```

Edited to format

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It covers things like what database software you are using, providing DDL and sample data, expected results, what you tried and what problems you couldn't resolve, ... . Aside: If you add a new permission won't _all_ the roles be missing for it?

Comment: @Ralph Sorry, I misread your question so I deleted my answer.  Sample data and expected output will really help here.

Comment: *"Roles that are missing new rows in the Permissions"* but roles aren't in your permissions table. That whole sentence is very confusing. Your table structure is very clear though. Please share an example of what happens to cause this issue "I insert a new permission into `RolePermissions` table for Role 1, but I would like `permissions` to also get that new permission that was created..."... ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Basically when a new permission is added into the permission table,  I would then like to add the new permission for each role into the RolePermissions table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your new permission and cross join all roles (to get all combinations of roles and new permissions).

```
INSERT INTO RolePermissions(RoleId, PermissionId)
    SELECT r.ID AS RoleId,p.ID AS PermissionId
    FROM Role r
    CROSS JOIN (
       --get all permissions currently not assigned to a role (presumably "new")
       select p.*
       from Permissions p
       left join RolePermissions rp on p.id=rp.PermissionId
       where rp.PermissionId is null
    ) p
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Aside: Since _new_ is undefined by the OP we can't tell what they really have in mind, but this query will add all roles for any permission that has zero roles in `RolePermissions`. If one were to delete the odd role/permission now and then and, by happy circumstance, wind up with a permission having no roles remaining then this query would repopulate the table.